# Get notified when TaggedValue of an element changes in Enterprise Architect

Tags: events, enterprise-architect

I am new in creating Addins for Enterprise Architect and I have this problem:
I have a diagram with elements which have TaggedValues. I want to get notified when the value of a TaggedValue changes and see the new value.
I saw that there is this event **EA_OnElementTagEdit** available but I can't seem to get it triggered. I also saw that the tagged value has to be of type **AddinBroadcast** but I can't seem to make it work. What am I missing?

I will put below a sample of my code:

```
            //creating tagged value
            EA.TaggedValue ob3 = (EA.TaggedValue)NewElement.TaggedValues.AddNew("Responsible", "val");
            ob3.Value = EEPROMBlocks.ElementAt(index).Responsible;
            ob3.SetAttribute("Type", "AddinBroadcast");
            ob3.Update();

            //event method
            public override void EA_OnElementTagEdit(EA.Repository Repository, long ObjectID, ref string TagName, ref string TagValue, ref string TagNotes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. This is simply not possible. The only way around is the `OnContext...` where you temporarily store the status of one element and look if a tag has changed when the context changes. I would not recommend that since it involved a lot of superfluous DB accesses.

Send a feature request (if you are an optimistic guy). Alternatively you should think of ways to get around this somehow else.

Comment: This discussion on sparx forum suggests that it is possible, and I found a few other with same info: https://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=4225.msg119506#msg119506

Comment: No. That's for special TVs only. For normal property edits on a TV you don't get any triggers/handles from EA. Maybe Geert will chip in since he seems having used that variant. And also you might explain more WHY you want to do that.

Comment: The use case is the following: I am creating a diagram based on an excel file which contains big amount of data. Diagram has elements with multiple tagged values. I need to be able to detect when a tagged value changes in order to make the same changes in the excel file.

Comment: You should probably think about comparing differences between (XMI) snapshots. TV changes should easily be detected (if there are no other major changes). I don't know LemonTree in detail but it might be worth a look.